# Am I supposed to add all the values in c1 to get answer 10?

Tags: c++

The answer to this question is 10. What does `c1.b.a + c2.a.b` mean?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    int a;
    float b;
};

struct B {
    int b;
    float a;
};

struct C {
    A a; B b;
}; 

int main (void) {
    C c1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}, c2 = {5, 6, 7, 8};
    cout << c1.b.a + c2.a.b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add the value of the `a` member of the `b` member of `c1` to the value of the `b` member of the `a` member of `c2` ? Is that what you're asking ?

Comment: Thanks Remy. I looked at the printout and it's helpful, but I agree that the reverse order is strange.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at definitions of each `struct`:

```
struct A {
    int a;
    float b;
};

struct B {
    int b;
    float a;
};

struct C {
    A a; 
    B b;
};
```

`A` contains two values: integer named `a` and a float value named `b`, `B` contains an integer named `b` and a float named `a` - it is pretty obvious. What about the last `struct`, called `C`? It is made of previously defined `struct A` and `struct B`, which have some "hidden", but accessible variables inside.

It is worth noting, that initializing values of `struct C` by the code:

```
C c1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
C c2 = {5, 6, 7, 8};
```

means, that it assigns values to variables in the order they appear in the `struct`, which is: `a.a, a.b, b.b, b.a`. By that we can easily say what are the values of every field:

- `c1.a.a = 1`
- `c1.a.b = 2`
- `c1.b.b = 3`
- `c1.b.a = 4`
- `c2.a.a = 5`
- `c2.a.b = 6`
- `c2.b.b = 7`
- `c2.b.a = 8`

Coming back to your question, which is "what does `c1.b.a + c2.a.b` mean and why does it return `10`" - the code first initializes values of each field and then adds these stored in `c1.b.a` and `c2.a.b`, which are `4` and `6`.

Answering the question from a comment, which is "why is `b.b` first and `b.a` second": while defining a `struct`, the order of types is very important, as the compiler must know how much memory it should assign. In your case, there is not much difference, as both `int` and `float` are 4 bytes, thus it will assign the first 4 bytes of `B` for an integer `b` and another 4 for a float `a` to work at its best.

Let's consider another structure defined below (compiled on 32bit, thus pointers are 4 bytes):

```
struct Example {
    int8_t a;    // 1 byte
    void *b;     // 4 bytes
    int8_t c;    // 1 byte
    int16_t d;   // 2 bytes
};
```

The first thing that could come to your mind is that after calling `sizeof(Example)` we would get `1+4+1+2=8` as a result and unless you add `__attribute__((packed))` directly after Example's definition, you would be wrong. Try not to use it very often though, as the performance might be worse.

Compiler wants to have the easiest access to the data inside structures, which means it aligns all the fields with the respect to the biggest type - in our case it is `void*`, but it cares about the order of variables inside the `struct` as well. It has to start at the byte which is divisible by 4 (here it's just 4), other data is aligned similarly with the respect to their size. Because of that, you may need to learn a bit about what padding and offset is. We should consider how the data is packed in memory, let's assume that `X` means that there is padding (so no data is saved in that part) and 1 letter corresponds to 1 byte. `Example` would be then `aXXXbbbbcXdd`.

With that knowledge we could sort all the fields inside `Example`, but note that **initializing sorted struct needs arguments in different order than before**. We could have:

```
struct Example {
    void *b;     // 4 bytes
    int16_t d;   // 2 bytes 
    int8_t a;    // 1 byte
    int8_t c;    // 1 byte
};
```

Then data would be packed as `bbbbddac`, which means the `sizeof(Example)` would return 8 bytes instead of 12 - we saved some memory!

Comment: c1.b.a is 4 and c2.a.b is 6.  Maybe the new question would be: why is c1.b.a = 4 instead of 3?

Comment: Missed that, I am sorry - in declaration of 'struct B' there is 'int b' as the first field, thus in initializing process it will first assign the value of 'b', and then of 'a'. Edit of my answer in progress.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Take a look at "upgraded" answer, it should tell you a little bit more about how it works and why.